# Aspect ratio not same after resizing thumbnails in PHP (GD)

Tags: php, gd

I am resizing an image to make thumbnails in PHP, but the aspect ratio is not same. I have gone from the code but I can't figure out what the problem is. Here is the code I am using.

```
<?php
$idir = "gallery/";
$tdir="gallery/thumbs/";
if(!file_exists($tdir)){
mkdir($tdir);
}
chmod($idir,755); 


/* It creates new thumbnails here */
function createThumbs($idir, $tdir, $tw, $th){
$dir=opendir($idir);
global $fname;
while(($fname = readdir($dir)) != false){
if($fname!='.' && $fname != '..'){
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($idir.$fname);
$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);
if($width>$height){
$nw=$tw;
$nh=$height*($th/$width);
}
if ($width < $height) 
{
$nw=$width*($tw/$height);
$nh=$th;
}
if ($width == $height) 
{
$nw=$tw;
$nh=$th;
}
$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0,0,0,0, $nw, $nh, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($tmp_img, $tdir.'tn_'.$fname);
}
}
closedir($dir);

}
if (!file_exists($tdir.'tn_'.$fname)) {
createThumbs($idir,$tdir,903, 603);
}
?>
```

Please help me find out what the problem is.

Also, Please share any other effective way to create thumbnails in php.

Answer (score 0):

Try using imagecopyresampled() rather than imagecopyresized().

Comment: I tried but it is still not maintaining the aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what I was doing wrong. The formula to calculate the new aspect ratio was wrong the new formula would be like this:

```
if($width>$height){
            $nw=$tw;
            $nh=$height*($tw/$width);
        }
        if ($width < $height) 
        {
            $nw=$width*($th/$height);
            $nh=$th;
        }
        if ($width == $height) 
        {
            $nw=$tw;
            $nh=$th;
        }
```